# dictionary of dictionaries(nested dicts)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some code:

```
for i in kofai:
    pav = get_main_pav(i)
    body = i.find_all("div", id=lambda x: x and x.startswith('game-wrapper-s-'))
    for bet in body:
        bet_pav = get_bets_pav(bet)
        kk = get_cof(bet)
```

I need to return this nested dict:

```
{pav: {bet_pav:[kk]}, {bet_pav:[kk]}, pav: {bet_pav: [kk]}}
```

How can I do that in a simple way?

Comment: That is not a valid Python data structure. Where's your code to do it a non-simple way?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: No, that's valid. `pav`, `bet_pav`, and `kk` are all variables in scope here.

Comment: @abarnert have you tried it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Oops, that's not a valid tuple, you need parens there… You're right.

Comment: what do you mean "parens"? thx

Comment: @user2745454: "parens" is short for "parentheses", as in `(` and `)`. In most cases, a bunch of comma-separated values is automatically a tuple, but when that's ambiguous (as it is inside a `dict` display), you need to wrap parentheses around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, how do you create each of the sub-dicts? At the point where you have the `bet_pav` and `kk` values you want, just do this:

```
subdict = {bet_pav: [kk]}
```

Now, how do you add them each to the main dict? Well, it looks like you wanted each `pav` to map to a tuple of sub-dicts, or maybe a list of them, but forgot the parentheses or square brackets. Either way, what you want to do is append to the existing tuple/list for each new sub-dict, starting with an empty tuple/list if this is the first sub-dict you've gotten. This is easier to do with a list than a tuple, so let's do that:

```
pavdict.setdefault(pav, []).append(subdict)
```

Or, if you prefer, you can just create `pavdict` as a `defaultdict(list)`, and then this line is just:

```
pavdict[pav].append(subdict)
```

---

Or, even better, if you think of this as constructing a dictionary all at once, instead of building it up by mutating insertions, you can write it as a comprehension:

```
def get_subdicts(i):
    body = i.find_all("div", id=lambda x: x and x.startswith('game-wrapper-s-'))
    for bet in body:
        yield {get_bets_pav(bet): get_cof(bet)}

pavdict = {get_main_pav(i): tuple(get_subdicts(i)) for i in kofai}
```

Comment: It works perfect. thank you. how can i learn that kind of magic :/

Comment: @user2745454: Have you read through the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html)? It explains how to add things to dictionaries—and, although it doesn't get to the shortcut of using `setdefault` or `defaultdict`, it does get to the shortcut of using comprehensions. (That being said, I'm sure there are better tutorials than the official one, I just don't know one.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for bet in body:
    bet_pav = get_bets_pav(bet)
    kk = get_cof(bet)
```

use

```
d = {pav:({get_bets_pav(bet):[get_cof(bet)] for bet in body})}
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than my solution, and should be easier to understand for a novice than I expected… except that's a generator expression, and you probably want a sequence (by using a listcomp instead of a genexpr or wrapping the genexpr in a `tuple` call).

Comment: Wait, no, it's worse than that, it's just a dict comp in parentheses; this is going to map each `pav` to a single dict with a bunch of values, rather than to a sequence of separate dicts, which is what (it seems like) the OP wanted.